# How to compare dates using perl?

Tags: perl

How can i compare two dates in the format using Perl:

```
"dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT"
```

> e.g.: 12 May 2013 10:10:20 GMT

I cannot install any external Perl modules.
Please advice.

Comment: "I cannot any install external Perl modules" — That [isn't very likely](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828)

Comment: "I cannot install any external Perl modules" - Then that is the first problem you should solve. If you can't install modules from CPAN then you're not using most of the power of Perl. Fixing that should be your highest priority.

Comment: If you can have your own Perl code on a system, you can install a Perl module. Either through [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib) or just copying them with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Perl v5.9.5 or newer, you can use `Time::Piece` core module. Here's a simple demonstration of relevant operations

- Convert the dates from string to `Time::Piece` object

  ```
  my $date = "12 May 2013 10:10:20 GMT";
  my $tp1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%d %B %Y %T %Z");
  my $tp2 = ...
  ```
- Find the difference between the 2 time

  ```
  my $diff = $tp2 - $tp1;
  ```

  which gives you a `Time::Seconds` object.
- Finally, display the difference in units of seconds (or something else).

  ```
  print $diff->seconds;
  ```
- Or you could just compare the two directly (thanks [stevenl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748019/stevenl))

  ```
  $tp2 > $tp1
  ```

---

References:

1. [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html)
2. [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)
3. [man strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) for format string to use with `Time::Piece->strptime`
4. [man strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for format string to use with `$tp->strftime`

   - Note that only format characters `aAbBcdHIjmMpSUwWxXyYZ%` are safe if you're using non-Unix system (for example, Window's Perl doesn't support the `%e` specifier).

Comment: Besides doing a subtraction, you can do a direct comparison: `$tp1 < $tp2`

Comment: @stevenl, thanks for the heads up. Added the info to the post.

Comment: Assuming you mean perl 5.9.5 (effectively perl 5.10) here; "perl 5.95" isn't right.

Comment: Duh doy, made a typo there. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the dates to the format `yyyymmddhhmmss` (e.g. `20130512101020`) and compare as strings. Handling the time zones might get tricky without modules, though.

Comment: hmm looks good. Don't have to anything with timezones here. yyyymmddhhmmss works in all cases?

Comment: @david: Try to find a case when it does not.

Comment: yep , i'm trying to but i don't think ill find one :)

Comment: Why did this answer get a -1. Are you kidding me?

Comment: @david Because any answer about dates that treats dates as simple strings or numbers is a bad answer.

Comment: @darch: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @choroba Dates are hard.  Shockingly so.  They involve more tradition than science and more politics than either of those.  Solutions that don't take these complexities into account contain the most expensive kinds of bugs:  those that appear to be working correctly during development only to fail hilariously (and possibly invisibly) after deployment.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular date modules is [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime). It has [a FAQ](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/FAQ) which may help you get started.

```
sub to_comparable {

       my ($date) = @_;
       my ($H,$M,$S,$d,$m,$Y) = $date =~ m{^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}), ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})\z}
          or die;
       return "$Y$m$d$H$M$S";
    }

    if (to_comparable($date2) < to_comparable($date1)) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: sorry but as i said i cannot install any external perl modules.

Comment: thanks,im trying, but converting to yyyymmddhhmmss looks simpler. what do you think?

Comment: Yeah! I have added codes in the answer. Try with that. It will work.