# How do I find the difference of two dates?

Tags: string, perl, parsing, datetime

I have date time strings in the format `2017-01-12T17:23:14.000-0800`

In Perl, is there any easy way to parse two dates like these and find the difference without individually extracting all the fields in the string?

For example given `2017-01-12T17:23:14.000-0800` and `2017-01-13T17:23:14.000-0800`, the difference I want would be 1 day (any reasonable format for this output is okay).

Comment: Search for modules that work with date-times.  The big boy of the lot is [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.42/lib/DateTime.pm), but there are others.

Comment: Possible answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040842/how-to-compare-dates-using-perl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates using perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040842/how-to-compare-dates-using-perl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%Z',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime('2017-01-12T17:23:14.000-0800');
my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime('2017-01-13T17:23:14.000-0800');

my ($y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S) =
   ( $dt2 - $dt1 )->in_units(qw( years months days hours minutes seconds ));
```

Alternatives

```
my ($y, $m, $d) = $dt2->delta_md($dt1)->in_units(qw( years months days ));

my ($m, $d) = $dt2->delta_md($dt1)->in_units(qw( months days ));

my $d = $dt2->delta_days($dt1)->in_units(qw( days ));

my $S = $dt2->delta_ms($dt1)->in_units(qw( seconds ));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/release/Time-Moment) supports the specified string representation. Since it's not a well-formed ISO 8601 representation we need to pass the lenient option to the [from_string](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment#from_string) constructor.

```
my $tm1 = Time::Moment->from_string('2017-01-12T17:23:14.000-0800', lenient => 1);
my $tm2 = Time::Moment->from_string('2017-01-13T17:23:14.000-0800', lenient => 1);

say $tm1->delta_days($tm2);
```

Output:

```
1
```

In the interest of full disclosure, I am the author of Time::Moment.